# Characters with accent counted as two characters in configurable products

Tags: magento

We sell configurable products that require a text field with a character limit (we sell personalized bracelets with customer's name on it).

So, we created on our product page a text field with 15 characters limit.

It is perfectly working if I put in this feld for example : "abcdefghijklmno" (which is 15 letters).

But if I put "abcdéfghijklmno" (which still is 15 letters but with the "e" acute), it just won't work, it says "please specify product option".

After a few tests, I found out that letters with accents are counted as 2 characters.

How can I avoid this error ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to you too :

You have to edit this file : app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Text.php

replace (around line 49) :

```
if (strlen($value) == 0 && $option->getIsRequire() && !$this->getProduct()->getSkipCheckRequiredOption()) {
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please specify the product\'s required option(s).'));
        }
        if (strlen($value) > $option->getMaxCharacters() && $option->getMaxCharacters() > 0) {
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The text is too long'));
```

by :

```
if (mb_strlen($value,'UTF-8') == 0 && $option->getIsRequire() && !$this->getProduct()->getSkipCheckRequiredOption()) {
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please specify the product\'s required option(s).'));
        }
        if (mb_strlen($value,'UTF-8') > $option->getMaxCharacters() && $option->getMaxCharacters() > 0) {
            $this->setIsValid(false);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The text is too long'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely an issue of character encoding — UTF-8 vs Latin1, for example.

You don't mention what programming language you're using. Taking a guess that it's a web app and odds that it's PHP, you may be able to use `mb_strlen` (which counts **characters**) instead of `strlen` (which counts **bytes**).

If it's not PHP, other programming languages have similar functions to count characters instead of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> É     É  É

Wrap your variable with `html_entity_decode($string);`

```
$example = html_entity_decode("abcdéfghijklmno");
print_r($example);
```

Try to learn [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

if you want to replace all acutes,

you must make a list and str_replace it before specify product option
[url_encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)